# pushViewController but do not hope the view appear

Tags: iphone

I used code to push an viewcontroller

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vViewController  animated:false];
```

but I prefer that view do something but not to display for uses, so I wrote in viewDidLoad of vViewController

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(2000, 2000, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

but nothing happened

Welcome any comment

Comment: set view.hidden=true got black screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A viewController controls a view.

If you do not want to have a view associated with your object that you are pushing to then you shouldn't be using a viewController.

Just use an NSObject.

Seems very odd to use a viewController and not show its view.